# How to neatly move some elements from std::set to another container?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Since iterator invalidates upon remove operation, how do I iterate with the least amount of code over all the elements of `std::set`, removing some of them ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// Filters the elements of a set:  elements that satisfy the predicate 'pred'
// are removed from the source set and inserted into the output.
template <typename TSet, typename TOutputIterator, typename TPredicate>
void extract_if(TSet& s, TOutputIterator out, TPredicate pred)
{
    for (typename TSet::iterator it(s.begin()); it != s.end();)
    {
        if (pred(*it))
        {
            *out++ = *it;
            it = s.erase(it);
        }
        else
        {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, never noticed `erase` returns an iterator:)

Comment: It's been a while since I've fiddled with it, but shouldn't your loop increment `it` in the `else` clause of your `if` statement, rather than in the `for` statement?

Comment: @Hurkyl:  Indeed it should.  Oops.  Thank you!

Comment: IIRC, the libstdc++ that ships with g++ doesn't provide the version of erase that returns the next iterator.  In that case, you need a couple more ugly assignments to achieve the same effect portably.  Anybody else experienced this?

Comment: Why not just use `std::remove_copy_if`, which more or less does exactly the same thing?

Comment: @Drew -- you need a newer version of g++ -- any version since 4.5 (which is "only" 5 years old) should have this

Comment: @ChrisDodd:  `remove_copy_if` does not remove elements from the input range.

Comment: @DrewHall:  Yes, it looks like `erase()` returns `void` in C++98/C++03.  So, if one finds oneself in this circumstance, he should work around it, e.g. `iterator current(it); ++it; s.erase(current);`

Comment: @JamesMcNellis:  Exactly what I've had to do in the past.  An abomination to be sure...

Comment: @ChrisDodd:  I use MinGW quite a bit--they just got 4.6 in November! :)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Thanks! I knew I have to use two iterators, but I was so tired I just couldn't put the code together.

Comment: Sorry but if I get it right the code in your answer will *copy* the elements to the destination, but it will not *move* them, which was the original question.